# Add User Control multiple times dynamically - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

I have an User Control (Web Forms) which i need to be added multiple times on the page. I have a button that is supposed to adds the controls again and again up to 10 instances. Also in the user control there is a remove button that should remove itself when clicked. This is what i tried but after adding one instance nothing happens. Meaning it adds one instance of the control and then stops working ...

```
MyControl ctrl = (MyControl )LoadControl("~/Controls/MyControl.ascx");
ctrlHolder.Controls.Add(ctrl);
```

Please notice that i have the ctrlHolder ajaxyfied using telerik AjaxManager.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i will change the approach and use the Telerik's RadListView control which suits my needs better. I can add as much controls as needed calling the ShowInsertItem() method and keep them saved into session. Sorry for bothering with the question and thanks for reading.